# Debug setting improper signal handler

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I've got an odd issue with Visual Studio 2013 (using 2012 CTP toolset). When an assertion fails, the error message is printed and then the program exits without the debugger breaking, so all the debug information is lost. So far I've used `atexit`, `set_terminate`, and `signal(SIGABRT, ...)` to break, but none have any success. Since I know that `abort()` is called and `abort` raises `SIGABRT` then it seems to me like somebody must have overridden my `SIGABRT` handler.

How can I catch where this occurs? I want to, say, break when somebody calls `signal(SIGABRT,...)`.